# How to get ASCII content exactly in byte[] C#?

Tags: c#, utf-8, hex, byte, ascii

I found many articles, reference links about the problem of reading content from byte[] array, but most of them do not decode the content properly. Is there a way to properly decode their contents? I have byte[] array for example, when converting to ASCII, they don't look like as expected result.

```
    byte[] raw_data = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 129, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 80, 1, 0 };
    Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(raw_data));
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(raw_data, 0, raw_data.Length));
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(raw_data, 0, raw_data.Length));
```

The results look very ambiguous.

[image]

Besides, I have used online converter to see the result, but it's also not good, can't see its correct value.

[image]

Any ideas, give me some advice. I get reference ASCII table from there .
[image]

Meanwhile, the byte[] array which i have, probably the value like this one.

```
S1F13
<L
>.
```

Comment: How was the data encoded?

Comment: Did you expect your byte array to decode to "S1F13", "<L" and ">."? Why did you expect that?

Comment: @shingo i can only get byte[] array value from client side. But I know one thing, the byte[6] and byte[7], it will be S1F13 , use this encoded ```_stream = "S" + (Convert.ToInt16(data[6]) - 128).ToString() + "F" + data[7].ToString();```

Comment: @Sweeper  Yes, I expected this, because I can only receive byte[] arrays from the incoming client side. I get it as length 16, and I know a few of them are byte[6] and byte[7] combinations, we have S1F13, use the following algorithm ```_stream = "S" + (Convert.ToInt16(data[6]) - 128).ToString() + "F" + data[7].ToString();```. There are other values I'm trying to figure out or decipher.

Comment: @Headshot So it's not ASCII then? Figure out the encoding first, and then [edit] this question to specify exactly how to decode it.

Comment: What you are showing is the decode process, if you don't know how is the original data encoded, why do you think the byte array contains ASCII content?

Answer (score 1):

same as many the comments, I'd suspect that something went wrong with the encoding. If you look up the characters on the hex-column of the ASCII table, you'll see that `80` (or `50` in hex) is the only value mapped to an alphanumeric character (i.e. `P`). That's a hint that you're decoding it just fine.

Since you already have a tool to convert your data, maybe compare your byte array to what the tool would produce for your expected result?